# Separate "includes" and "templates" directories for Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm looking for a way to have separate `'template'` and `'includes'` directories with Jinja2 and only allow

For example say I have the following directory layout:

```
/templates/
    base.html
/includes/
    header.html
    footer.html
```

I'd like to ensure that the application level `get_template` only has `base.html` visible to it, and that the `include` template statement only has `header.html` and `footer.html` available to it.

I'm aware that I can add both directories to the loader, eg:

```
loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(['/templates/', '/includes/'])
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
template = env.get_template('base.html')
```

But this doesn't give me the strict separation of the two different template types that I'm looking for.

Is there any way to enforce this separation, so that `.get_template('base.html')` will succeed, but `{% include 'base.html' %}` will fail?

Is there some way I can use two different loaders, one to get the template initially, and a second that'll be used when rendering that template?

For example, could I do something like this?...

```
base_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/templates/')
includes_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/includes/')

base_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=base_loader)
includes_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=includes_loader)

template = env.get_template('base.html')
template.env = includes_env
```

Answer (score 1):

The `template` instance has an `environment` property, so it looks like it's possible to do this...

```
base_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/templates/')
includes_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/includes/')

base_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=base_loader)
includes_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=includes_loader)

template = base_env.get_template('base.html')
template.environment = includes_env
```

This should ensure that only files in the `/includes/` directory are available to the `{% include ... %}` template statement.

Edit:
changed env to base_env in line 7 of the code.

Comment: By the way, @Tom Christie's solution didn't work for me but guided me to the solution who did: >>>template.environment.loader = includes_loader